# Update ListView without freezing UI

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to create ListView which every 4 seconds add item and set focus on last item.
Problem is that my Fragment wait for asynctask is over and only then show(all time asynctask work its white screen)

```
 public class LogFragment extends SherlockFragment {
    private ListView lvList;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private UpdateTask mTask = null;
    String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile" };
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.log_fragment, container, false);
        lvList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvLog);
        final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
            list.add(values[i]);
        }
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getSherlockActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        lvList.setAdapter(adapter);
        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("myLogs", "LogFragment:OnCreate");
        mTask = new UpdateTask();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mTask.execute();
    }
```

And my AnyncTask:

```
 public class UpdateTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        int temp = 10;

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            getSherlockActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while (temp-- > 0) {
                        try {
                            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(4);
                            adapter.add("Lol" + String.valueOf(temp));
                            lvList.setSelection(lvList.getAdapter().getCount() - 1);
                            Log.d("myLogs", "Added from Async");
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            return null;

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        }
    }
```

How to solve my problem?

Comment: adapter.add("Lol" ... )   - LOL!

Comment: I thought you were joking around.  You started an AsyncTask that starts another thread on the UI thread to update the UI in a loop and sleep.  I thought it was a joke.  Sorry.

Comment: No :( What method can offer you?

Comment: What's the point of the background thread(the `AsyncTask`) if you 're going to run the entire code in the main UI thread using `runOnUiThread()`? Post on the UI thread **only** the adapter updates and not the actual `sleep`.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html) and do not use an AsyncTask in the way you are doing it right now. The idea behind AsyncTask is to do computation not on the UI thread and you are blocking the UI thread again with this `runOnUiThread()` stuff. If you want to use your custom AsyncTask implementation sleep in the `doInBackground()` method and parse the results back to the UI in the `onPostExectue()` method. Never use a reference to the UI thread like `lvList`in the `doInBackground()` method. If you want to do that use [WeakReference](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html).